# Understanding recursion with the help of Iteration

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

```
  def unZip(master3):    
       c = len(master3)
       sub1=''
       sub2=''
       for i in range(0,c,2):
           sub1+=master3[i]
           sub2+=master3[i+1]
       print(sub1,",",sub2)
```

---

basically I have written this code that separates alternative char from string and shows them separately,

I have been trying to convert or comprehend this with recursion but I have been failing lately.

Here is my try, can someone tell me how should I approach it?

```
def unzip(a):
    storage1=''
    storage2=''
    storage3=''
    storage4=''
    if len(a)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        if len(a)>=1:
            storage1=a[0::2]
            storage2=a[1::2]
            storage3+=storage1
            storage4+=storage2
            print(storage3,storage4)
            return unzip(a[0]+a[1:])
```

---

Comment: `unzip(a[0]+a[1:])`. You're passing the whole string back to the function.

Comment: thanks morgan for editing it, I am first timer so I didn't know how to do it :)

Comment: No problem, in the future, if you highlight your code and hit Ctrl + K, it'll format it correctly.

Comment: Hi @Rectifier, welcome to SO.  Please consult the [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page for how to improve your questions.  For example, please be sure to include what problems/errors you are having exactly.

Comment: isn't the string getting sliced in the recall? :/

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix, Thanks for suggesting, I will take care of it from now on.

Comment: just for clarification, why are you doing this in recursion? it's not really a function that i would try recursively....

Comment: I was asked by my tutor to try doing it with recursion. I mean it's easier to get the following result with iteration but still he wants me to do it this way

Comment: You're not really doing anything recursively with this right now. Your slicing produces the output you expect from what I can tell

Answer (score 0):

instead of using slicing to determine your strings you should be taking one character at a time off your string and then recalling your recursive function like so

```
def unzip(s, a, b='', c=''):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return b + ', ' + c
    if s%2 == 0:
        b += a[0]
    else:
        c += a[0]
    return unzip(s+1, a[1:], b, c)

print unzip(0, 'HelloWorld')

Hlool, elWrd
```

What that does is it starts with the string `a` and alternates between adding to `b` or `c` with the variable `s` depending on whether it is even or odd. Add the first letter of `a` to either `b` or `c` and then remove that letter from `a`. Then call the function again but with `s+1`. If the length of `a` is zero then return `b` and `c` and then print your result

To get the same results with what you have you could simplify yours down to

```
a = 'HelloWorld'
storage1=a[0::2]
storage2=a[1::2]

print(storage1,storage2)

('Hlool', 'elWrd')
```

The slicing takes care of getting every other letter in `a` and then you can just print that. The way you have it set up now it will just keep passing `a` and become an infinite loop since the size of `a` will never change.